# C# delegate with string reference to c++ callback

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, delegates, managed

I wrote a C# application that uses an unmanaged c++ dll via managed c++ dll.
In the unmanaged dll, there's a callback that one of its params is `std::string&`.

I can't seem to find the right way to wrap this with the managed dll.
When I use `String^`, the callback works, but the C# application does not get anything in the string.
When I used `String^%`, things started to crash in other places that does not seem to be related (maybe memory corruption).

So my question is, what's the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't copy-paste code here, but I'll try to explain again.
I can't use marshaling in the managed c++ section because I'm not calling a function, but passing a c# delegate for a callback.

In the unmanaged dll, I have a callback that requires a function like this: `void Func(unsigned int, int, std:string &)`.

My goal is to pass a c# delegate from my program to that callback, so in the unmanaged code, 
I made a delegate like this: `delegate void DEL(unsigned int a, int b, String ^ c)` and a function like: `void mFunc(DEL ^ del)`, and that function marshal's the delegate into a cb that the unmanaged callback subscribe function accepts. The unsigned int and int works fine, but the string is always `""` when the C# function is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code would help me understand better and give a better answer; but there is no automatic conversion or marshalling of String^ to std::string. You would need to do to marshalling yourself to get the string back to the C# code. A quick search can provide with details on how to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42zy2z41.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the marshalling can deal with std::string.  I think you need to make your own callback that passes char * and then write the glue code between the two.

Also, once the delegate is marshalled into a callback, that callback does not count as a reference to the object that the delegate might have been made from.  So if the delegate is not a static method, you need to stuff it somewhere for the lifetime of the unmanaged callback.